# How to save octave plot with greek symbol µ

Tags: plot, octave

i want to save my plot to a jpg.

When the code build the plot it shows the µ-Symbols, but in the jpg it shows \mum. 
What can i do to solve the problem?

It works with graphics_toolkit gnuplot, but the legend is very big and covers the plot, but  i can save it with µ.
Thanks!

Here is a code sample:

```
 x=-10:0.1:10;
y=sin(x);
figure
plot(x,y,'*b')

legend('Name: \mum')
```

Comment: where's the code?

Comment: If you want to use the opengl toolkits you have to use GNU Octave 4.2.0 which fixed this in print.

Comment: Thanks the new version has helped!